# Pass non-Woocommerce product to Woocommerce cart

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a site for a client, that has a feed-driven database table, updated daily with a massive new list of products (around 250,000). I'd like to use Woocommerce, as I'm familiar with it and the checkout/customer accounts features would be ideal. However, I'd need to pass products from the custom table to Woo's cart, as I can't create Woocommerce products from the custom table.

I was convinced I could form custom items and pass them to the cart (without a Woocommerce product ID), though I'm finding it difficult to find documentation on that now.

I can create items on-the-fly, at the order stage, using this code in a custom payment gateway:

```
$item_id = wc_add_order_item( $order_id, array( 'order_item_name' => $fee['name'], 'order_item_type' => 'fee' ) );
wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_total', wc_format_decimal( $fee_total ) );
```

Looking to do the same, at the cart stage. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What I would suggest is:
1. Create new woocommerce product, when you add to cart. This way you can display it in the cart as well.
2. Store this mapping info from your massive list to woocommerce checkout product, maybe in your custom table.
3. Do a regular checkout.
4. Remove the product.

This might sound simple, I am also struggling to achieve it. Might need to go through the documentation for api calls, but this should be possible.

Comment: Thanks Pratik. I did something very similar to this in the end. I added a wc_id column to the feed table, then when the item was added to cart, it creates a woocommerce product, adds it to cart and adds the woocommerce id to the product on the feed table.
I used woocommerce_add_cart_item_data to add custom data to the cart item and then link the WC product to my feed product as it goes through checkout and order.
The only difference is I'm not deleting the product. Then, if another customer adds the item to their cart it can reuse the WC product. Let me know if you need further help.